# Pass a variable to a different class

Tags: python

I have a class with two functions. I am trying to pass `user_input` to `CreateDirectory.createDir()`, but I get this error `NameError: name 'genDir' is not defined`.  How can I pass the `user_input`  variable to `CreateDirectory.createDir()`?

My code below:

```
class CreateDirectory():

    def genDir(name,x=0):
        while True:
            dir_name = (name + (' ' + str(x) if x is not 0 else '')).strip()
            if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
                os.mkdir(dir_name)
                return dir_name
            else:
                x = x + 1

    def createDir(dir):
        genDir(dir)

class PyShell(Cmd):
    global default_shell_prompt
    default_shell_prompt = ("Shell > ")
    prompt = (default_shell_prompt)

    def do_exit(self,inp):
        PyShellFunc.clearScr()
        sys.exit(0)

    def do_mkdir(self,inp):
        prompt = (default_shell_prompt + "mkdir > ")
        running = True
        while running:
            global user_input
            user_input = input(prompt)

            if user_input == ("exit"):
                running = False
                prompt = (default_shell_prompt)
            else:
                try:
                    os.mkdir(user_input)
                except:
                    CreateDirectory().createDir()
```

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Comment: you need to do `self.genDir` Or look at `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: You would usually share **instances** of a class with instance attributes and not class attributes.

Comment: If your class has no state, in other languages you might use a static class but in Python there is no need as you can collect functions in a module. Why do you need CreateDir to be a class, why not simply have genDir as a function in the module? Also, what is the point of createDir?

Comment: Or better yet, why not make gerDir a private method of PyShell? And then just pass user_input to it, no reason to make it global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making `genDir` a private method of your `PyShell` class, and then replacing all those `global` variables with instance variables:

```
class PyShell(Cmd):

    def __init__(self, default_shell_prompt = "Shell > "):
        self.default_shell_promt = default_shell_prompt
        super.__init__() # might not be necessary, not sure what you're doing with Cmd

    def exit(self, inp): # Why pass in inp if it's not being used?
        PyShellFunc.clearScr() # what is PyShellFunc?
        sys.exit(0)

    def mkdir(self, inp):
        prompt = f"{self.default_shell_prompt}mkdir > "
        dir_name = None
        while dir_name != "exit":
            dir_name = input(prompt)
            dir_name = PyShell._get_dir_name()
            os.mkdir(user_input)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_dir_name(name, count = 0):
        while True:
            dir_name = f"{name} {count if count > 0 else None}"
            if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
                os.mkdir(dir_name)
                return dir_name
            else:
                return _get_dir_name(name, count + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have three choices here: 
1) define this function as object's method
2) define them as class's method
3) as static method

1) as object's method

```
class CreateDirectory():

    def genDir(self, name,x=0):
        while True:
            dir_name = (name + (' ' + str(x) if x is not 0 else '')).strip()
            if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
                os.mkdir(dir_name)
                return dir_name
            else:
                x = x + 1

    def createDir(self, dir):
        self.genDir(dir)
```

2) as class's method

```
class CreateDirectory():

    @classmethod
    def genDir(cls, name,x=0):
        while True:
            dir_name = (name + (' ' + str(x) if x is not 0 else '')).strip()
            if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
                os.mkdir(dir_name)
                return dir_name
            else:
                x = x + 1

    @classmethod
    def createDir(cls, dir):
        cls.genDir(dir)
```

3) static method

```
class CreateDirectory():

    @staticmethod
    def genDir(name,x=0):
        while True:
            dir_name = (name + (' ' + str(x) if x is not 0 else '')).strip()
            if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
                os.mkdir(dir_name)
                return dir_name
            else:
                x = x + 1

    @cstaticmethod
    def createDir(dir):
        CreateDirectory.genDir(dir)
```

Comment: Thank you for this response! I didn't even think about static method.